# Markov Regime Switching Regression Models - Time Varying Probabiliites

Tags: regression, switching, markov

I am looking into estimating a markov regime switching model with time varying probs. Please help me if you know a simpler way to estimate such model.

Answer (score 0):

This [paper](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2083332) might answer your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can easyily implement this model with MarSwitching.jl package in Julia language: https://github.com/m-dadej/MarSwitching.jl

Just use: `model = MSModel(y, k, exog_tvtp = df)` where `y` is target variable, `k` is number of states and `df` is a variable explaining the process of transition probabilities.